# How to remove specific Row widget on action

Tags: flutter, dart, setstate

How can I remove specific Row in my screen in Flutter Web Page?
I have 2 Rows in StatefulWidget "EditForm2". Both rows have Text, TextFormField and also Button to remove whole row.
What is a good way to achieve this? I assume that I have to use setstate() method and  removeAt() on
Row table, but I don't know how to use this.
I want to make dynamic form where user can delete and add input controls.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class EditForm2 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _EditForm2State createState() => _EditForm2State();
}

class _EditForm2State extends State<EditForm2> {
  var Rows = <Row>[];

  Row RowFsLink;
  Row RowGeoInfo;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ///first Row
    RowFsLink = new Row(children: [
      Expanded(
        flex: 3,
        child: Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 30.0, right: 30.0),
          child: Text('Link',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black54,
                fontSize: 20.0,
                letterSpacing: 0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
              )),
        ),
      ),
      Expanded(
          flex: 6,
          child: Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 30.0),
              child: TextFormField(initialValue: 'test link'))),
      Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 30.0),
        child: Ink(
          decoration: ShapeDecoration(
            color: Colors.red,
            shape: CircleBorder(),
          ),
          child: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.remove,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ]);

    Rows.add(RowFsLink);

    ///second Row
    RowGeoInfo = new Row(children: [
      Expanded(
        flex: 3,
        child: Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 30.0, right: 30.0, bottom: 50),
          child: Text('Geo',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black54,
                fontSize: 20.0,
                letterSpacing: 0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
              )),
        ),
      ),
      Expanded(
          flex: 6,
          child: Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 30.0, bottom: 50),
              child: TextFormField(initialValue: '0.50;0.44'))),
      Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 30.0),
        child: Ink(
          decoration: ShapeDecoration(
            color: Colors.red,
            shape: CircleBorder(),
          ),
          child: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.remove,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ]);

    Rows.add(RowGeoInfo);

    return Column(children: this.Rows);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the state variable `isVisible` before calling the `Rows.add` method:

```
var _isVisible = true;
...
onPressed: () {
  setState(() {
    _isVisible = false;
  });
},
...
```

Inside the `build` method:

```
if (_isVisible) {
  Rows.add(RowGeoInfo);
}
```

This will dynamically add / remove the row at each refresh. Everytime you call `setState` the page is refreshed.

Comment: Thank You, it works, but if I'm correct I have to also clear array of Rows in setstate method?:
var Rows = <Row>[];
becuase now when I remove first Row, Page is refrshed with only second Row, but another two Rows are added (first and second) so there are 3 rows then.

Comment: To clear the rows,  no need to reinitialize the variable `Rows`. (BTW, don't name variables with an uppercase. That's for classes. Names starting with _ are private names, local to the class or file. Names without _ are public names.) Declare `_rows` as `late final Row[] _rows;`. In `initState`, create the object: `_rows = Row[];`. In the `setState`, clear the rows: `_rows.clear();`. This is the most common way to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

First declare a bool variable. Inside the onPressed you want to change the variable on click, we wrap it in a setState so that the widgets rebuild themselves.

```
bool isVisible = false;
 onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  isVisible = true;
                });
              },
```

To hide or show the Row we simply do this.

```
(isVisible)? Row(children: [],) : Container()
```

This means that if isVisible = true we show the Row() if its false we show an empty container.